# Add static IP settings to custom rom

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, custom-roms

I'm trying to store default static ip settings in a custom rom.

I write the SSID and Password to /etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf and that works well for Wi-Fi

But how do I add the static IP settings (gateway, fixed ip) for Wi-Fi (and Ethernet)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you do, the device may not be able to connect other wifi networks...

Comment: I want to do that because I want to set up a couple of android devices with the same rom and the same static ip settings. I don't want to reduce the manual configuration as much as possible. One step is setting up the static ip settings.

Comment: manual configuration? IS there no dhcp on it? :o that is an odd one! Like as I have mentioned in my previous comment, what if you went to a public wifi hotspot - it will fail. :)

Comment: static IP addresses have higher precedence over dynamic...? me fcekn memory is gone now... le sigh

Comment: I'm using the devices for a signage system and it's okay that they won't connect to public hotspots then. Would be great though if it's still possible to deactivate the static ip settings at some place...

Comment: What android version is your ROM? :)

Comment: It's currently Android 4.1.1

Comment: You might have to manually specify that in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` - yes, if you're rooted, that is where it is stored.

Comment: as for static ip - that is stored within the settings database, rather more correctly - Settings Content Provider. As you have indicated, you have made this custom rom? yes? compiled from scratch? there should be an overlay directory in your build - add in the static IP and gateway into the `config.xml` file found in the overlay directory.

Comment: Didn't build it from scratch. That means I don't have an overlay directory (Am I right?) 
I modified and repacked an existing rom. I used the wpa_supplicant.conf to store the ssid and password. But I don't know how to store the static ip, gateway etc. in there...

Comment: (I'm repacking the system.img)

Comment: Ahhhh okie, fair enough... yes you're correct you dont have the overlay directory... Am afraid you'd need to build it from scratch to shovel into the Settings content provider to insert the static ip, gateway etc, or write a simple oneshot program to run on first start to insert the values.

Comment: First start option sounds good :) Any resources, tutorials, links about this method? I tried before to write xmls to /data/data/... but failed. 
(THANKS alot by the way!)

Answer (score 1):

Save the following in one of the init scripts in the ROM

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
setprop net.dns1 192.168.1.1
ip addr show
ip route show
```

Where eth0 in this case, is an ethernet adapter attached via USB.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my Samsung S3 Mini (Jelly Bean 4.1.2) worked 100% on my Wi-Fi router but failed to connect to the Internet with my Wi-Fi repeater - stuck on "obtaining IP address..." message. I have now set a static IP and it works 100% on both the router and the repeater. If you need multiple static IP options then check out "Wi-Fi Static" application.
I found the answer courtesy of Motorola, and repeat it below, at https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/68989/p/7901,8013,

To setup a Static IP Address on your Motorola Xoom, follow the steps below:

```
Touch Apps
Touch Settings
Touch Wi-Fi settings
Touch Add Wi-Fi network
Enter Name under Network SSID, and touch Save
Touch and hold the "network name", and touch Modify network
Select Static under IP settings, and enter the specific network information

Tip: You can also adjsut your security and Proxy settings.
Touch Save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set ip with ifconfig and gateway with route when you are rooted.  I  used it to change  the tcp buffer.